# how to change the lock images to unlock images in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

am having game with 10 levels. i want to change the second level lock image to unlock when first level is completed.

am using 20 images ( 10 locked and 10 unlocked).

am using cc menus to display the number images.
for example(code):-

```
 CCMenuItemImage *startButton12 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"ten_new-lock.png"
        selectedImage:@"ten_new-lock.png" target:self
        selector:@selector(ten:)];

    menu1  = [CCMenu menuWithItems: startButton3,startButton4,startButton5,startButton6,startButton7,startButton8,startButton9,startButton10,startButton11,startButton12, nil];
      menu1.position = ccp(240,30);
      [menu1 alignItemsHorizontally];
      [menuLayer1 addChild: menu1];
```

am using below code for remember the level completed.

```
 int lastLevelCompleted= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"levelCompleted"];
    if(currentLevel >lastLevelCompleted){
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setInteger:currentLevel forKey:@"levelCompleted"];
```

**now, how to change the lock to unlock images.

*( if am doing here wrong)there is other way to solve means provide that. i have to implement that one.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same idea in one of my games. I solved it with separate lock and done icons that I have positioned on top of each menu item that represents a level.

Just create your menu items normally. Don't try to represent locked or done states with the menu item's icon. Instead create a smaller *locked* and *done* icons that you will instantiate as sprites and position on top of each menu item.

Here is the relevant part of my menu layer's init method (I'm using a sprite atlas to store all my images):

```
// I save the state of each level as a character in a NSMutableString: 
self.completedState = 0x0043; // "C" (Completed)
self.openState = 0x004f; // "O"
self.lockedState = 0x004c; // "L"
self.dungeonAvailabilityState = @"COLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL"; // in reality I get this string from a global object

// calc the position for the dungeon icon at row, column
x = (column*56)+148;
y = 244-(row*56);

// get the dungeon state
stateIndex = (row*columns)+column;
dungeonState = [self.dungeonAvailabilityState characterAtIndex:stateIndex];


// calc the position of the badges using offset from the menu item's icon
lockedX = x - DungeonsScreen_BadgeXoffset;
lockedY = y - DungeonsScreen_BadgeYoffset;
doneX = x - DungeonsScreen_BadgeXoffset;
doneY = y + DungeonsScreen_BadgeYoffset;

if (dungeonState == self.lockedState) {
 // add the lock icon
 [super badgeIconFromFrame:@"icon_lock.png" xPos:lockedX yPos:lockedY spriteTag:t++];
}
```

and my helper method badgeIconFromFrame looks like this:

```
- (void) badgeIconFromFrame:(NSString*)spriteName xPos:(float)x yPos:(float)y spriteTag:(int)t {
        CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);

        CCSprite* badgeSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteName];
        badgeSprite.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
        [self addChild:badgeSprite z:zIndexDecoration tag:t];   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could set a `disabledImage` when you create each `CCMenuItemImage`:

```
// create items by delclaring also a "disabled" image
CCMenuItemImage *menuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:normalImage 
                                                   selectedImage:selectedImage 
                                                   disabledImage:disabledImage 
                                                          target:self 
                                                        selector:@selector(callbackMethod)];
```

Then just switch the state of the button as requested:

```
// then just use setIsEnabled to switch the state
[menuItem setIsEnabled:NO];
```

Cocos swaps the images for you.

Answer (score 0):

What about `(void) - setIsEnabled:` method of CCMenuItem ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works:

```
if(unlock){
 [menuLayer1 removeChild: menu1 cleanup:YES];

CCMenuItemImage *startButton12 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"ten_new-unlock.png"
    selectedImage:@"ten_new-unlock.png" target:self
    selector:@selector(ten:)];

menu1  = [CCMenu menuWithItems: startButton3,startButton4,startButton5,startButton6,startButton7,startButton8,startButton9,startButton10,startButton11,startButton12, nil];
  menu1.position = ccp(240,30);
  [menu1 alignItemsHorizontally];
  [menuLayer1 addChild: menu1];
}
else
{
CCMenuItemImage *startButton12 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"ten_new-lock.png"
    selectedImage:@"ten_new-lock.png" target:self
    selector:@selector(ten:)];

menu1  = [CCMenu menuWithItems: startButton3,startButton4,startButton5,startButton6,startButton7,startButton8,startButton9,startButton10,startButton11,startButton12, nil];
  menu1.position = ccp(240,30);
  [menu1 alignItemsHorizontally];
  [menuLayer1 addChild: menu1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did u try using db (sqlite) to store the value of locked or unlocked.
It will definitely work.
But it is a big process.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [menuItem setNormalImage:lockedButton];

LockedButton being another CCMenuItemImage with a new file.